# loadstring() which contain a function in Lua

Tags: lua

Say, I have this memo line text:

```
Memo.Lines.Text = 'print('Hello World')
local test = Memo.Lines.Text
loadstring(test) ()

--result: Hello World
```

Now, if something like this:

```
Memo.Lines.Text = [[
function playTest()
 local a = 10
 local b = 20
 local c = a + b
 print('This is a test of a math calculation: ')
 print(a..' + '..b..' is '..c)
end
]]

local test = Memo.Lines.Text
loadstring(test) ()
playTest()

-- result: error attempt to call a nil value 'playTest'
```

How to return the function from strings / as Memo lines text above?

Comment: the provided code is ok, given that you define Memo and  Memo.Lines somewhere. Please delete your post and your answer. you must have forgotten the parentheses after `loadstring(test)` to get this error